# How to properly use a parameter of type class?

Tags: java, class, inheritance, parameters

In java, I'd like to do something like this

```java
    public class Tata{ 

        public static void f(){
            //something
        }
        public static void g(){
            //something
        }
    }

    public class Titi{ 

        public static void f(){
            //something
        }
        public static void g(){
            //something
        }
    }

    public class Toto{

        private Class c = Tata.class; //or Titi.class 

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            c.f();
            c.g();
        }
    }
```

To be precise, I'd like to be able to freely switch between classes *Tata* and *Titi*, to use their respective methods *f* or *g*.

This doesn't work as intended, as I get the **cannot resolve method 'f()'** error. Simply replacing *c.f();* and *c.g();* with *Tata.f();* and *Tata.g();* works fine, but defeats the purpose of using a parameter. How to solve this?

Comment: There are several problems with this. There is no instance of `Tata` to call `f` on. Also `c` is not defined as `Tata`, so of course you cannot call `f` on it

Comment: Class is just one more layer to your class.. It contains a couple of base methods as toString and equals. if you want to use the `f` function from your `tata` class you will need to cast that `class c` to `((Tata)c).f()`

Comment: Just do `private Tata t=new Tata()` and access methods like `t.f();`

Comment: btw why you want to use Class instance?

Comment: Joakim, yes f() is a static method. I edited the question.
f1sh, f is static, so no instance is needed. c not being defined as Tata is the whole purpose of my code, as I want to be able to call methods f and g from different classes, not solely from Tata.
Michael, casting c as Tata defeats the purpose of me trying to parameterize some class on which I can call f, but then freely be able to change class whenever I like.

Comment: dan1st, I have multiple classes such as Tata in which methods f exist. I wish to be able to freely change between these classes through the use of a parameter c.

Comment: What you just explained is the sole purpose of interface. Instead of polluting the code with a lot of static functions and without actual initialization you will have a constructor that will take an Interace A with the function f(). Then you pass a class implementing interface A thus function f and you can freely change the implementation. This way you are secure the function will exists. You wont need reflections or any casting. ( also you can use @ before a name so that user will be notified you spoke to him )

Comment: Totally agree with @MichaelMichailidis Use interface and avoid static functions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Will turn the comment into answer after all.. The correct (Java) way to deal with what you want is the use of interface. So in your demo code the implementation would be the following:

```java
public interface TheFGFunctions {
    void f();
    void g();
}
public class Tata implements TheFGFunctions {
    @Override
    public void f() {
        //something
    }
    @Override
    public void g() {
        //something
    }
}
public class Titi implements TheFGFunctions {
    @Override
    public void f() {
        //something
    }
    @Override
    public void g() {
        //something
    }
}
public class Toto {
    private TheFGFunctions c;
    public Toto(TheFGFunctions c) {
        this.c = c;
    }
    public void notStaticFunction() {
        c.f();
        c.g();
    }
}
```

This way is totally typesafe with zero exceptions to deal with!

Answer (score 3):

You could use reflections:

```
private Class c = Tata.class;

public Toto() throws Exception {
    c.getMethod("f").invoke(null);
    c.getMethod("g").invoke(null);
}
```

Here my Tata class

```
public class Tata {
    public static void f() {
        System.out.println("ffff");
    }

    public static void g() {
        System.out.println("gggg");
    }
}
```

Output on `new Toto()` call:

```
ffff
gggg
```

**Update (call with parameters):**

```
public Toto() throws Exception {
    c.getMethod("f", String.class).invoke(null, "paramValue1");
    c.getMethod("g", String.class).invoke(null, "paramValue2");
}

public class Tata {
    public static void f(String param1) {
        System.out.println("ffff " + param1);
    }

    public static void g(String param2) {
        System.out.println("gggg " + param2);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
ffff paramValue1
gggg paramValue2
```

Comment: How does one add parameters to *f* or *g* through a reflection? I didn't specify, but my function is actually *f(this)*, instead of *f()*.

Comment: I added example with parameters to the answer.

Comment: Sorry, missed that parameter is `this`. Just change `String.class` to `Toto.class`  : `c.getMethod("f", Toto.class).invoke(null, this);`

Comment: Even though this is a correct answer,  I chose Michael Michailidis' answer, since it is easier for me to adapt my code to work with an interface, than adapting it to work with the Exceptions your solution creates.

Answer (score 3):

You *cannot* access a static method polymorphically.  The Java language doesn't support it.

The reason your current approach fails is that `c` is an instance of the class `Class`, and the class `Class` doesn't define methods `f()` or `g()`.

(The methods that it does define are listed in the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) for `Class`.  Note that `Class` is `final` so you can't create a custom subclass with extra methods.)

---

The simple alternative is to use reflection; e.g.

```
     Class c = 
     Method f = c.getMethod("f");
     f.invoke(null);   // because it is static
```

But note:

- This is not statically type-safe.  The compiler cannot tell when you make the mistake of trying to use a static `f()` on a class that doesn't have such a method.
- There are a few exceptions that you need to deal with; e.g. missing methods, incorrect signatures, methods that are not static, methods that don't have the correct access.

---

Other answers have proposed creating an interface and wrapper classes to make certain static methods dispatchable.  It will work and it will be compile-time type-safe (!) but there is a lot of boiler plate code to write.

---

@Michael Michailidis commented:

> Thus interfaces!

Yea ... kind of.  You can only dispatch polymorphically on instance methods declared on an interface.  That implies that you must have an instance of `Tata` or `Titi`, and call the methods on it.  My reading of the Question is that the author wants to avoid that.

(IMO, the avoidance is the *real* problem.  You are better of *not* trying to avoid instance methods.)

FWIW, you can declare static methods in an interface (since Java 8), but they would behave the same as if you declared them in a class.  You wouldn't be able to dispatch ...

Comment: thus interfaces!

Answer (score 0):

Write a wrapper interface

```
interface CWrapper {
    void f();
    void g();
}
```

and wrapper class factory method for each Class containing the methods

```
class CWrappers {
    CWrapper forTiti(Class<Titi> titiClass) {
        return new CWrapper() {
            void f() { Titi.f(); }
            void g() { Titi.g(); }
        }
    }
    // another factory method for Tata
}
```

Then you can use that:

```
public class Toto {
    private CWrapper c = CWrappers.forTata(Tata.class); //or forTiti(Titi.class)

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        c.f();
        c.g();
    }
}
```